# Using Kalman Filter to integrate sensor data

Tags: computer-vision, kalman-filter

I have two cameras which are retrieving the angle between two points (call them center and end) and the horizontal. I have added noise to the sensing of the end of the arm equal to a gaussian with mean 0 and standard deviation of 5 pixels.

How would I go about making a Kalman filter to integrate the two readings in order to generate a more accurate reading?

Answer (score 0):

Form estimate Zest as weighted sum of two readings Z1 and Z2 in the following way:

> Zest = Z1*V2/(V1+V2) + Z2*V1/(V1+V2)

V1, V2 are variances of Z1 and Z2 readings respectively.